# Kafka Streams: Reprocessing application coordination

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

**Scenario:**

I have a full-retention KafkaStreams application.
It has one event topic, and several output topics, which include web events, users, customers, etc.
A topology runs over it generating sessions and relations between entities.

I have several (in the thousands) websites, each of which sends events to the same topic.
Consumption from output topics is sent to an analytical DB.

I have original event data partitioned by `modulo (website, user) / numPartitions` in order to have a good data distribution.

**Problem:**

When certain metadata changes for a website, I would like to be able to reprocess all data for that website (and only that website).

I could launch a separate application to reprocess all data from offset 0, ignoring data from other websites, and make it stop when finished. This is nice because I can scale up the reprocessing application depending on the size of the website, without affecting the regular application.

However, there are some issues:

- How could the regular application learn about the new state generated after reprocessing?
- How could the two applications be synchronized without stopping the regular application(i.e. how the reprocessing can be stopped safely)?